# type for email text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

what's the correct `inputType` for `email` in EditText?

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/email"
  android:layout_width="200dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textEmail"
  android:inputType=""/>
```

Comment: so, it's easier to create whole topic instead of write your question in google?

Comment: I google it and this is the first hit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need one, the default is fine.  You only need an input type when you want special behavior-  numeric only, password, things like that.

Edit:  if you want an email address, then use textEmailAddress as others suggested.  The body of an email, which is how I read the question, can be default.  Subject has textEmailSubject, but tends to be ignored.

Comment: no, you need it to bring the @ simbol on the front layout for example.

Comment: Ah, that's a very keyboard specific behavior.  Maybe the default keyboard does that, I haven't used it in a year or so.  Also, there's a type for an email address and subject, but none for the body of the email.  So it depends on which one he wanted.  And subject on many (most?) keyboards would be ignored and used as plain text.

Answer (score 10):

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> in Eclipse then it will bring up the menu of options available and narrow them down as you type.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ticketMail1 = findViewById(R.id.ticketMail);


    private boolean validateEmail(EditText email){
    String emailinput = ticketMail1.getText().toString();

    if(!emailinput.isEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailinput).matches()){

        return true;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid Email Address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```